# Fréchet derivative of norms of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am trying to find Fréchet derivatives of the norms in $\mathbb{R}^n:$ $$f_{1}(x) = ||x||_1:= \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i|,$$
$$f_{2}(x) = ||x||_2:= (\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i|^2)^{1/2},$$
$$f_{3}(x) = ||x||_3:= \displaystyle\max_{1\leq i\leq n}\{|x_i|\}$$

Each of this norms are not Fréchet differentiable on $(0,0)$ because directional derivatives do not exist in such point.
$f_2$ is Fréchet differentiable in $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ sch that $x\neq 0$ because is composition of Fréchet differentiable mappings (square root and projections satisfies this) and have derivative $f^{'}_2(x)y=\frac{<x,y>}{||x||_2}$ where $<x,y>$ is the usual inner product.

But for other norms I think they are not Fréchet differentiable but I cannot see why. I was trying to prove that they do not have directional derivatives in any point but I do not get any useful.

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Comment: $f_1$ are not differentiable exactly on $\cup_{i=1}^{n}\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:x_i = 0\}$, and $f_3$ are not differentiable exactly on $\cup_{i\neq j}\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:x_i=x_j\}$.

Comment: That was so helpful. Thanks.

Comment: All the norms have a one sided directional derivative at each point. The are convex and hence differentiable ae.